# Open application to edit text files from the command line

Tags: command-line, text-editor, kate

When installing the [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) in OSX you also get an `edit` command which allows you to open any text file from the command line.

Is it possible to have a similar functionality in Ubuntu to type some command on the terminal to open a file in a specific text editor (say Kate)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To open a file using `kate`, you can run something like:

```
kate filename
```

This might show some messages like:

```
kate(3702)/kdecore (services) KMimeTypeFactory::parseMagic: Now parsing  "/usr/share/mime/magic"
kate(3702)/kdecore (services) KMimeTypeFactory::parseMagic: Now parsing  "/home/user/.local/share/mime/magic"
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon
```

To remove these messages, redirect the error output stream to `/dev/null`:

```
kate filename 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to continue using the same terminal, add an `&` after the command:

```
kate filename 2>/dev/null &
```

---

If you want to run `edit filename` to open it, you could create a bash function in your `~/.bashrc` file. Add the next code to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
edit() { kate "$@" 2>/dev/null & }
```

Comment: This gets closer to what I was looking for. Thanks for actually running the commands and see the problems that would arise with the most obvious solutions. I guess what I'll do is to create a new command which I can just call as `edit filename` to run the whole `kate filename 2>/dev/null &`.

Comment: @Juan: I've added an example for doing that. The `$@` is needed in case you need to pass additional options like line number. As an alternative, you can tweak this function to support `edit filename linenumber`.

Comment: You have a bug in your answer, and I can't seem to edit it. You forgot the quotes around `$@` (should be `"$@"`), which means that your script will fail with filenames what contain spaces.

Answer (score 26):

You can open (Up to my knowledge) any of the editors like this:

**NAME_OF_EDITOR FILENAME**

`gedit filename` (Ubuntu)
`kate filename` (Kubuntu)
`bluefish filename`
`kwrite filename`
`libreoffice filename`

You can even open a web page the same way
`firefox filename.html`
`chrome filename.html`
`banshee filename.ogg` or .mp3

You can see the tendency here..

Comment: Actually it should be `gedit filename &` otherwise the terminal remains unusable. The same thing happens with `kate` but, even with the `&` it makes the terminal unusable because it starts spitting debug (or whatever) information to the terminal. Is there a way to avoiding the `&` in the end at all? As I do with `edit` from TextWrangler?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer from [Lekensteyn](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33950/open-application-to-edit-text-files-from-the-command-line/33954#33954) is (at least closer) to what I was looking for.

Comment: True, you can add the **&** or even add **2>/dev/null** to it to not output error and stuff in the console if you want to keep using it.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use the command `edit` in Ubuntu also because you are used to do so you could also define an alias for your favourite editor like for Kate:

```
alias edit='kate'
```

To make this alias permant just add this line to `~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any graphics environment and you are running on console you can always use:

```
vim foo.txt
nano bar.txt
pico foo.html
emacs bar.xml
...
```

and so on falls back to the first answer..

Comment: "emacs -nw" or "xemacs -nw" if you want VT100 (x)emacs even inside a windowed environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLI command for the desired editor to open and edit files.For example `gedit` in gnome or `kate` in KDE.

Just type:

```
kate filename
```

to open file in kate.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use a classical terminal where mcedit is my prefered editor, and often like to pass a line number, to correct a program/script.

To uniformely call them `edit source.sh 123` I wrote this script, which I placed as 'edit' in the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
#   - edit a file using mcedit or gedit, depending on X11 or console invoking.
#   - jump to specified line, if any.

Xedit=/usr/bin/gedit

if [[ $TERM = "linux" ]]; then
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        mcedit $1
        else if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
#           echo "edit invoked\t/usr/bin/mcedit +$2 $1" >> /tmp/edit.log
            /usr/bin/mcedit +$2 $1
            else if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
                /usr/bin/mcedit
            fi
        fi
    fi
    else if [[ $TERM = "xterm" ]]; then
        # scheint nicht zu helfen
        # LANGUAGE=C
        export LC_ALL=C
        if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
            $Xedit $1
            else if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
#               echo "edit invoked\t/usr/bin/scite -open:$1 -goto:$2" >> /tmp/edit.log
                # $Xedit -open:$1 -goto:$2
                $Xedit +$2 $1 
                else if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
                    $Xedit
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Use see old debug instructions from when I used scite, not gedit, as graphical editor.

Something, which doesn't work this way, is opening of multiple files like this:

```
 edit *.html
```

if there is more than one html-File, so the pattern gets expanded to multiple files.

Valid invocations are:

```
 edit 
 edit foofile 
 edit foofile 123
```

from X or terminal.